# RPi script to periodically collect data from Arduino through serial port

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I'm not used to Python.

The script opens serial communications with an Arduino unit and send commands to and receives information from the Arduino. It is intended to run indefinitely until the system is shut down or pulled out of field deployment/laboratory testing.

The `time.sleep()` calls with offsets are assurances that repeated calls won't eventually result to time drifts, as mentioned [in this Stack Overflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python/). I don't trust myself with this. I need confirmation that I placed the `start_time = time.time()` lines in proper locations. This time drift issue is crucial because the script shall run for months.

`read_data()` sends a command to the Arduino, which tells it to give the Pi new data. Data sets written by the Arduino vary in length, so I can't use `serial.read(expected_bytecount)`. Data sent between start and stop bytes (e.g. *data1,data2,data3#) is always valid, so I don't need to do checks there. Is my algorithm here enough for my task?

`wait_until_sampling()` keeps the Pi from being busy around the clock. Reading data occurs every `15th` and `45th` minutes of an hour. I thought of using `minutes % 15 != 0`, but there are the `0th` and `30th` marks. I also tried doing away with `datetime` but I can't get the minutes of the system time from `time`. Is there a simple way to improve this algorithm by dropping `datetime`?

```
import datetime
import time
import serial


def read_data():
    data = []
    start_time = time.time()
    arduino.write(b'S')
    time.sleep(360.0 - ((time.time() - start_time) % 360.0))
    while True:
        temp = arduino.read().decode(encoding='UTF-8')
        if temp  == "*":
            while True:
                temp = arduino.read().decode(encoding='UTF-8')
                if temp == "#":
                    break
                else:
                    data.append(temp)
            break
    return data


def wait_until_sampling():
    start_time = time.time()
    dt_now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    while (dt_now.minute != 45) and (dt_now.minute != 15):
            time_now = time.time()
            dt_now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
            time.sleep(1.0 - ((time_now - start_time) % 1.0))



arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
time.sleep(20.0)
data_returned = []
while True:
        wait_until_sampling()
        data_returned = read_data()
        # post-process data_returned here
```

Comment: What level of timing precision are you aiming for?

Comment: @200_success  Not entirely sure how to answer that, but I'd like to keep up to the seconds precision intact since I'm checking for  the `15th` and `45th` minute-marks for each second passed. Knowing that the script will run for months, I worry that the sub-seconds will eventually spill drifts to the seconds and upwards.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A simple technique to avoid busy wait is to

  ```
  import select
  ....
  select.select([], [], [], timeout)
  ```

  The `timeout` is simply `target_time - current_time` in seconds. Since `select` interprets it as a floating point, the granularity is in  milliseconds at least.

  I see no possibility for time drift.
- The nested loops in `read_data` do not look right. Consider instead

  ```
  def read_data():
      data = []

      temp = None
      while temp != '*':
          temp = arduino.read()...

      while temp != '#':
          temp = arduino.read()...
          data.append(temp)

      return data[:-1]
  ```
- I am not sure why do you `sleep()` before reading the response.

Comment: Clarification: the 'select.select()' would replace the lines inside the 'wait_until_sampling()' function? As for the sleep, I have to wait for the data to be written to the serial port since the Arduino will take samples over a 5-minute interval after receiving the command, and send the averaged results.

Comment: @Nogurenn Yes, `wait_until_sampling()` becomes `timeout = compute_timeout(); select.select([], [], [], timeout);`. As for sleep, the `read()` is blocking and your program wouldn't proceed until Arduino replies - with `sleep` you are only creating a chance of serial overrun. Both `select` and `read` end up in system calls, letting your system do other things.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I don't have to `sleep()` because the program already just waits for valid input? I intended for the RPi to not be busy while waiting for the ~5-minute sampling time of the Arduino. Can I just call another `select.select()`, or `read` as you said will let my system do other things?

Comment: @Nogurenn You got it right.